# Which cooker do you suggest for heating 150l (40 gallons) batch?

Tags: large-batch

I would like to brew bigger batches, however heating up more beer requires more energy. I would like to use gas or propan-butan. 
I have found something like this: http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f11/200-000-btu-natural-gas-burner-14742/

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My batch size is typically 1/4 your size but in doing research for a burner I settled for a 60k burner over a 150k burner. Forget the myth about caramelizing the wort with a hotter burner, the best advice after weeks of research was from a young guy at my local sportsmen store. he suggested efficiency vs. productivity, and in using this logic I would suggest configuring two smaller burners to increase surface area effected by the heat source or find a larger "commercial sized" burner to increase surface heating. I wish I had more experience with batches of this size, but I hope my suggestions helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have figured out I need 31 kW for heating up this big batch in an hour.